# PostgreSQL: use subquery for domain value check

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a domain in PostgreSQL that uses values from a table as a check. Is this possible?

I tried the following:

```
CREATE DOMAIN language_code AS character(2) CHECK(VALUE in select language_id from languages);
```

but that gives an error: `ERROR:  cannot use subquery in check constraint`.

I know I can use foreign keys to enforce this kind of check, but that is rather cumbersome for values used in many places, and I thought this would be cleaner and easier to do.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Inserting or deleting rows in that table would change your domain definition.

Comment: @Bergi I notice Oracle also does not support this. But why should you not be able to do it against a list that might change? After all that is what an FK constraint does. Only that requires more setup.

Comment: The CREATE DOMAIN command does not support using subqueries within the CHECK. An alternative to achieve a similar effect as what you're looking for restricting values to those present in a specific table without directly using a subquery in a domain definition, is to utilize triggers or a custom function.

Comment: A domain value is checked when it is constructed, not when it is stored somewhere. It might occur as a nested part of another type, it might be a local variable in a function, it might be a temporary value during a query evaluation. None of these support foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

The comments to my question set me on the right path. I managed to find a solution for my requirement, that gives me what I want, by declaring a function and then using that in the domain definition.

The effect is that when I try and insert a value that is not in the table, it gives an error, similar to how a foreign key constraint behaves (except that I am not interested in updating all related tables if the backing table - in this case the table of languages - is updated).

The advantage to going this route is that when I have a datatype where the possible values are backed by a table, I can simply include that in a table definition, instead of having to add a foreign key constraint each time.

(It would be nice if the domain definition could be extended to simply include the name of a table and column containing the allowed values - I think I understand why a subquery would be too complicated).

The function takes a language code as input, checks it against the table and then returns `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the value is found:

```
create or replace function language_exists(lang_id char(2))
returns boolean
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare 
    lang_exists boolean;
begin
    select case count(*) when 1 then true when 0 then false end as exist
    into lang_exists
    from languages where language_id = lang_id;
    return lang_exists;
end;
$$;
```

(Sorry, my first time I am writing an SQL function; perhaps there are ways to improve this?)

Then my domain definition looks as follows:

```
CREATE DOMAIN language_code AS character(2) 
CHECK(language_exists(VALUE));
```

Now I have a table that uses the domain:

```
CREATE TABLE public.order_type_texts (
    order_type_id bpchar(4) NOT NULL,
    language_id public.language_code NULL,
    description varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT order_type_texts_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_type_id)
);
```

Test inserting records:

```
-- This succeeds:
insert into order_type_texts values
('ERGO', 'en', 'Externally sourced regional');

-- This fails (non-existent language code 'zx'):
insert into order_type_texts values
('ERGO', 'zx', 'Externally sourced regional');
```

On failure, I get the following message:

```
SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: value for domain language_code violates check constraint "language_code_check"
```

Perhaps this can be improved, so I will dig a bit further.

Comment: "*perhaps there are ways to improve this?*" - write a `LANGUAGE SQL` function that simply does `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM languages WHERE language_id = lang_id)`